# How do you obscure an Email Address in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I would like to send subscribers to a link that passes their email address as a url query parameter. Is there a way in ExactTarget to obscure the email address so it cannot be easily read in the url? For example instead of:

http://www.website.com?e=email@address.com

It would look something like

http://www.website.com?e=xSeffWrf3gtH

where the value of e = email@address.com.

Comment: I don't know ExactTarget very well but do you have access to the code that generates the URL and the code that receives the request i.e. the code that fires when www.website.com is hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Base64Encode()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Base64Encode) function in ET to encode it and then decode it on the target page using the [Base64Decode()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Base64Decode) function.

Check out [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54374/carrying-qs-parameter-with-form-submission-on-landing-page/54403#54403) post.  It has a code sample.

EDIT: (Snip from other post)

First page:

```
%%[
    SET @processingPageURL = MicrositeURL(NNX, "attr1", "value1", "attr2", "value2")
    SET @preferenceCenterURL = MicrositeURL(NNZ, "processingURL", Base64Encode(Replace(@formURL, "=", "_")))
]%%
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@preferenceCenterURL)=%%">To the preference center</a>
```

Target page:

```
%%[
    SET @formURL = RequestParameter("processingURL")
    SET @formURL = Base64Decode(Replace(@formURL, "_", "="))
]%%
<form action="%%=RedirectTo(@formURL)=%%" method="POST">
```

Comment: You could also you use EncryptSymmetric/DecryptSymmetric if you need something more secure.

Comment: @Timothy - submit as a different answer.

Comment: Adam - would you mind adding the relative code snippet, in case that link ever dies.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something more secure, try [EncryptSymmetric](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#EncryptSymmetric)/[DecryptSymmetric](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#DecryptSymmetric).  This is more secure than the Base64 solution, but significantly more complex.  The documentation is too extensive to be posted here, but do have a look at the links.

**EncryptSymmetric(S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10)**

> Encrypts plain text data using the supplied algorithm and encryption
>   values. You can supply either a value or a valid external key for the
>   password, initialization vector, and Salt. You can also use the
>   external keys if you have previously created keys in the Key
>   Management section of the user interface. Otherwise, the function
>   generates a password using the password parameter or stored value, the
>   Salt parameter or stored value, and the IV parameter or stored value.
>   If you do not pass or reference an initialization vector, the function
>   uses the password parameter or stored value as the initialization
>   vector. All output provided by this function uses base 64 encoding.
>
> This function treats Salt and IV values (either directly provided or
>   looked up by key) as hex strings, with each pair of characters
>   repesenting a single byte in the larger strings. Do not attempt to use
>   these values as a cipher string, as you cannot successfully encrypt
>   those strings using this function.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy. I think this is more than what I'm looking for but may be useful for someone else.

Comment: @Timothy have you actually managed to decrypt the message (using PHP) encrypted by ET's EncryptSymmetric function?

Comment: I've only done it using C#.  Know that the encryption algorithms are often different across languages.